# JavaScript file load order and dependency management

Tags: javascript

Just wondering about this...

I have several separate javascript files, that all contain code based on the module pattern. A few of the modules have some of the others as dependencies. If i know that none of the code would be called on the HTML until the page is loaded, does the order in which the files load still important?

Is the fact that the module code sits inside an immediate function enough to trigger the requirement that the other modules be loaded already?

I am prepared to look into the RequireJS library if need be, but just wanted to know if what i am going is ok first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If possible set up your dependencies so you can load and set up all your modules when the javascript file gets loaded (i.e. use a self executing function).

And then call a `.init` or equivalent function on all your modules in a `.ready` block. That way you can explicitly call any functionality requiring dependencies after all your files have loaded.

An example:

```
foo.js
(function() { 
    function initFoo() { ... }
    ...
    window.namespace.foo = {
         init: initFoo
    }
}());

bar.js
(function() { 
    function initBar() { ... }
    ...
    window.namespace.bar = {
         bar: initBar
    }
}());

main.js
(function() {
     $.ready(function() {
          window.namespace.foo.init();
          window.namespace.bar.bar(); // dependancies on foo
     });

}());
```

Any code that doesnt have dependancies can be executed in the closures of `foo.js` & `bar.js` and any dependant code can be called through your `init` function on `.ready` once all the files have loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but after some more research and consideration, i think i'm going to go with a RequireJS solution.

Comment: @JasonMiesionczek I think the RequireJS solution is a bit heavy weight for my liking. Also it makes my code ugly! I prefer to design my code so the independent code loads immediately and the dependant code gets started manually. As long as you don't have ridiculous circular dependencies then the code should be fine.

Comment: my problem is, i do have circular dependencies, which makes designing my own solution that much more difficult.

Comment: @JasonMiesionczek circular dependencies mean you go and rewrite your code so its not shit. Circular depencies are a design failure.

Comment: After a taking a look at my code, and following your advice, i've written a Dispatcher module, which will have the references to the other modules. The other modules will fire off events when important things happen, and the dispatcher has listeners added to those events to react appropriately. This way, only one module needs to know about all the others, and tight coupling is kept to a minimum.

Comment: @Jason Event driven design is the way to go. Alternatively you can use MVC frameworks like backbone.js

Comment: backbone.js looks interesting, i'll have to check it out. thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the call to "window.namespace.foo.initFoo();" be "window.namespace.foo.init();"?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the files have been loaded by the time execution starts, the order of loading does not matter.

It *might* be possible that some JavaScript engines begin to compile scripts as soon as they are downloaded, so this *might* affect that. But the scripts will still run!