# Order of jquery / .js scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having real problems with my application due to the order I render the .js scripts. For example in http://jsfiddle.net/qCAW3/1, the items will not become draggable until I change the order in which the js scripts are loaded.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Can anyone shed some light as to what causes this. If I change the order to get the draggable items to work, then other javascript parts of my application stop functioning.

Comment: You have to include jquery.js before other scripts that use it, including before jquery-ui.js or other jQuery plugins. (This concept doesn't just apply to jQuery, by the way.) What are the other scripts that you are having trouble with?

Comment: It's pretty simple, you can't call a function before you defined it.

Comment: It will be helpful to watch your javascript console. The console will display errors such as `$ is undefined in 'jquery-ui.js'`. Whenever you see that `$` us undefined it probably means that some script using jQuery is being loaded before jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies, that's when some code depends on other code.  And on a webpage, JavaScript files are executed in the order they are declared.  Which is important for dependencies!

Lets say you have two `.js` files that look like this:

```
// person.js
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
  alert("Hi, " + name);
}
```

And another file:

```
// roster.js
var roster = [
  new Person("Alex"),
  new Person("Eddy")
];

for (var i = 0; i < roster.length; i++) {
  roster[i].greet();
}
```

If we load `roster.js` first, it will explode.  The `Person` constructor would not yet be available, and calling it anyway would raise an expection.

If you load `person.js`, and then afterward load `roster.js`, then you have `Person` available when the roster code runs.

---

In your case, you need to load jQuery before any code that uses jQuery, for exactly the same reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It happens that it was another script causing my application to break when the .js script were in correct order. Fine explanation thanks.

Comment: _"it will explode"_ - Yeah, I lost a really nice laptop that way. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Typically when one file depends on another, it has to be loaded after.  That's in a very general sense.  Since your problem is centered around load order and timing, I'd suggest looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914810/javascript-file-load-order-and-dependency-management).  Basically, make sure not to execute anything before all files being depended upon finish loading.